# Is it possible to implement Database backed Push Notifications in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, push-notification, signalr

I'm working on a client and server application, in which client requests 'client-specific' data from the server. I'm planning on switching to ASP.NET WebAPI for server so that client can take advantage of available .NET APIs to query server for data.

This scenario works perfectly fine when the client initially connects and requests data from server, However, instead of client constantly polling for data, it should just establish a persistent connection and the server should be able to monitor the database for changes and push new data to the client that has stale data. I came across SignalR and found that it can be used with WebAPI, but can't figure out how to integrate it with database monitoring i.e. a thread or process that is constantly monitoring database for updates. Any solution? I'm open to other non-WebAPI based .NET technologies as well - basically anything .NET based that will cut-down on the development time.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Web API supports `PushStreamContent`. Take a look at the section "Push Content" in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/04/23/using-cookies-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx. Here, a timer triggers content written into the stream but you can use that to poll database and write into response or build some other better mechanism

Comment: Is "PushStreamContent" designed to support apps that maybe active for days at a time?

Answer (score 0):

signalR could fit your requirement. You can broadcast a message to all your user or just to part of them. Your client could be a browser (with javascript) or a .net client (WPF or else).
From the server, you can call a method on the client just like that

```
Clients.All.MyMethodOnTheClient(param1, param2)
```

or

```
Clients.Client(connectionId).MyMethodOnTheClient(param1, param2)
```

The topic is too broad to answer it in 5 min. I can advise you [to start here.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20)
Then browse [the server api guide](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server), the javascript guide and the .net client guide.
Don't worry. It's quite fast to have a complete tour.

Comment: It seems to be calling a specific method on client to pass parameters. Does this work with any type of non-javascript client i.e. C# desktop application, iOS app etc?

Comment: For C# desktop application it works fine => http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client For iOS app, I don't know